# how to set font size of excel cells using excellibrary.dll

Tags: c#, telerik, export-to-excel

i export large data to excel using excel library dll but can not able to set font size to bold and can not able to implement borders in excel.How can i resolve this issue?

Comment: What type of control you are working in Telerik.. is it a webapp or windows app.?

Comment: its a web application..there is  a telerik grid we are implementing custom exporting to excel using excel library dll but i can not able to formatting text like bold and border

Comment: So what you are saying is.. the Telerik controls for ASP.Net/Ajax.. Am i right..

Comment: if that is the case, You will have the ItemDataBound event right?

Answer (score -1):

For example if you have the export button like below :-

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Export" CommandName="Export" OnClick="btnExport_Click" />
```

The below code will change the size of `EmployeeID` heading to `20pt`

```
protected void RadGrid1_ItemCommand(object sender, GridCommandEventArgs e)
 {
   if (e.CommandName =="Export")
     {
       GridHeaderItem HeaderItem = (GridHeaderItem)RadGrid1.MasterTableView.GetItems(GridItemType.Header)[0];
       HeaderItem["EmployeeID"].Style["font-size"] = "20pt";
     }
 }
```

The same way you can edit, each of the rows using

```
protected void RadGrid1_ItemCommand(object sender, GridCommandEventArgs e)
     {
       if (e.CommandName =="Export")
         {
           GridDataItem dataitem = e.Item as GridDataItem;
           item["Name"].Font.Size=FontUnit.Large; //You can also change the unit to pixel too.
         }
     }
```

In the above code, Name is a text column to be formatted.